# Coerce vectors in entire dataframe into appropriate class in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with around 3000 columns. Each column is a factor - but some are conceptually numeric.

I wrote this quick for loop to transform the appropriate columns but it doesn't seem to be working the way I intended. Essentially, I check and see if coercing a vector into numeric results in the mean of that vector being `NaN`, and if not, proceed to coerce the vector into numeric, otherwise, coerce it into character.

Here is the code:

```
 for (i in 1:length(data)) {
     ifelse(!is.nan(mean(as.numeric(as.character(data[,i])), na.rm=TRUE)), 
     as.numeric(as.character(data[,i])), as.character(data[,i])
      )  
 }
```

The problem is that it doesn't change my data.

Comment: You have to assign it back to the variable... data[,i] <- ifelse(...)

Comment: @Roland's question should be considered. You can force data to be a particular class by using colClasses  in any of the `read.*` functions and get better performance in the bargain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a data.frame of character columns:

```
DF <- lapply(iris, as.character)
sapply(DF, class)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
# "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"
```

You can then use `type.convert`:

```
DF <- lapply(DF, type.convert)
sapply(DF, class)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

This would also convert to logical, integer or complex values as appropriate, but I assume you won't mind that. Basically, this is what `read.table` uses.

However, I wonder why you have a data.frame of character columns to begin with ...

Comment: This works great - thanks for the tip. The answer to your question is the data was stored in Mongo as all character type. So, I think when I read it into R, via `RMongoDB` the data is stored as such... anyway this works great.